# how to make two different widgets in one screen?

Tags: android, widget

I'm makeing a project that can show defferent watches to users.The watch has different clock dial.I want to make two different widgets(the watch)in one screen and the watch has different time and clock dial.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own control and then include that control twice in a single screen.

```
package com.sample.ui.control;

public class MyControl extends LinearLayout {
    public MyControlContext context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_my_control, this);
    }
}
```

You can add extra code as necessary.  The xml file control_my_control is the XML for your watch.  In that XML, be sure the outer element is a  element.

For the view that will contain two of these, you use them like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.sample.ui.control.MyControl android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/control1" />
    <com.sample.ui.control.MyControl android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/control2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now I have the problem like this.

    public class MyClockView extends View implements Parcelable{
      public MyClockView(Context context){

}
}

you know,if a class extends view,it must have a constructor method that has a Context.I want the class implements Parcelable so I can send parameter by Intent.My problem is how can i implements Parcelable without a public MyClockView(){} method?(the parameter method have no parameter)


sorry,my english is not well, so i can't express clearly.can you understand what i mean?

Comment: Why do you want to make a Parcelable view?  If there's some parameters in your view that you want to send to an Intent, you can use the Intent extras, or you can make a separate class that implements Parcelable and use that as in the intent.  The view itself probably shouldn't be Parcelable.